# CodeIgniter: Class 'CI_Controller' not found

Tags: codeigniter, php

I've extended CodeIgniter controller by adding MY_Controller.php in Application/Core folder. It works fine, but Now when I add following code on `error_404.php` page in `Application/errors`, I get error.

**Code causing problem:**

```
<?php $ci =& get_instance();?>
<?php $this->ci->load->view('header')?>
```

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in path\to\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 231
```

The line 231 of the `system\core\CodeIgniter.php` is:

```
function &get_instance()
    {
        return CI_Controller::get_instance(); 
    }
```

How can I fix this so that I can load view in the error_404.php without changing anything in system files.

PS. I'm using latest version.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think CI_Controller is loaded yet. The Exception class is handling the 404 page output using an `include`.

In the old days, I used to use straight `include`s to piece together a template, or do a `file_get_contents()` or cURL request to my 404 page URL, but they finally did something about it. In 2.0 you can define a custom 404 page in `routes.php`:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'controller/method/parameter';
```

It's still [not a perfect solution](https://bitbucket.org/ellislab/codeigniter/issues?q=404), but the easiest way now is just to use the route.

Note that `base_url()."controller/method/parameter"` must be a valid url, and you should make sure to set a 404 header in the controller that outputs the page too (it's not done automatically for some reason).

Comment: If you are using Composer for autoloading, this error might also be caused by a missing vendor directory. In this case, fix by running `composer install` on your server (recommended) or upload via FTP aren't able to run a command on your server.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when following the CodeIgniter tutorial here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

The problem was I tried to access the url:

localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.1/application/controllers/pages.php

instead of addressing the url:

localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.1/index.php/pages/view

I know it has been around 18 months since you asked that question but maybe it can help someone else :)

Answer (score 5):

or you could try this,
perhaps bit dirty but i think it will work for me

update your exception to

```
function show_404($page = '', $log_error = TRUE)  {
   if ($log_error)   {
     log_message('error', '404 Page Not Found --> '.$page); 
   } 
   header('Location: http://www.########.###/error/error_404');  
   die();
}
```

then just create controller to handle the redirect, perhaps with different errors you can use the same controller

that way you will get your dynamic header and footer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php $ci =& get_instance();?>
<?php $ci->load->view('header')?>
```

Once you assigned the instance of CI to $ci you can just use $ci->load->view('header) throughout your file.

Comment: I tried that as well, doesnt work. The error is caused by the first line, as it remains same even if i remove the second line.