# Class 'CI_Controller' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\ninja\system\core\CodeIgniter.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is code of mu controller file

```
<?
if(!defined('BASEPATH')) exit ('not allow a direct access');

class password extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->module('layout');
        ini_set('display_errors','On');
        error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('text');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //$this->load->model('forgetPassword/forget_mdl');
        //$data['package_detail'] = $this->register_mdl->package_detail();
        $this->layout->getHeaderLayout('Forget Password');
        $this->layout->getTopBarLayout();
        $this->layout->getHeaderTopLayout();
        $this->blade->render('forgetPassword/forgetPassword_view');
        $this->layout->getFooterLayout();
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of $config['log_threshold'] in config.php?

Comment: 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758681/codeigniter-class-ci-controller-not-found

2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207937/codeigniter-command-line-error-php-fatal-error-class-ci-controller-not-foun

Answer (score 0):

controller name and file name must match. Also controller name is expected as "Password" not "password"

```
class Password extends CI_Controller{
```