# Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I try to access the localhost for my xampp server, an error shows up like this:

> Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 226

CodeIgniter.php line 222-227:

```
require BASEPATH.'core/Controller.php';

function &get_instance()
{
    return CI_Controller::get_instance();
}
```

Full CodeIgniter.php

```
<?php
 if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
 exit('No direct script access allowed');
 }
/*
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2014, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/*
 * System Initialization File
 *
 * Loads the base classes and executes the request.
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  codeigniter
 * @category    Front-controller
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/
 */

/*
 * CodeIgniter Version
 *
 * @var string
 *
 */
 define('CI_VERSION', '2.2.0');

/*
 * CodeIgniter Branch (Core = TRUE, Reactor = FALSE)
 *
 * @var boolean
 *
 */
    define('CI_CORE', false);

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the global functions
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
require BASEPATH.'core/Common.php';

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the framework constants
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    if (defined('ENVIRONMENT') and         
file_exists(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/constants.php')) {
    require APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/constants.php';
} else {
    require APPPATH.'config/constants.php';
}

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Define a custom error handler so we can log PHP errors
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
set_error_handler('_exception_handler');

if (!is_php('5.3')) {
    @set_magic_quotes_runtime(0); // Kill magic quotes
}

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Set the subclass_prefix
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Normally the "subclass_prefix" is set in the config file.
 * The subclass prefix allows CI to know if a core class is
 * being extended via a library in the local application
 * "libraries" folder. Since CI allows config items to be
 * overriden via data set in the main index. php file,
 * before proceeding we need to know if a subclass_prefix
 * override exists.  If so, we will set this value now,
 * before any classes are loaded
 * Note: Since the config file data is cached it doesn't
 * hurt to load it here.
 */
    if (isset($assign_to_config['subclass_prefix']) and     $assign_to_config['subclass_prefix'] != '') {
    get_config(array('subclass_prefix' =>     $assign_to_config['subclass_prefix']));
}

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Set a liberal script execution time limit
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
if (function_exists('set_time_limit') == true and @ini_get('safe_mode') == 0) {
    @set_time_limit(300);
}

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Start the timer... tick tock tick tock...
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
$BM = &load_class('Benchmark', 'core');
$BM->mark('total_execution_time_start');
$BM->mark('loading_time:_base_classes_start');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the hooks class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
$EXT = &load_class('Hooks', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Is there a "pre_system" hook?
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
$EXT->_call_hook('pre_system');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the config class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
$CFG = &load_class('Config', 'core');

// Do we have any manually set config items in the index.php file?
if (isset($assign_to_config)) {
    $CFG->_assign_to_config($assign_to_config);
}

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the UTF-8 class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * Note: Order here is rather important as the UTF-8
 * class needs to be used very early on, but it cannot
 * properly determine if UTf-8 can be supported until
 * after the Config class is instantiated.
 *
 */

$UNI = &load_class('Utf8', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the URI class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
$URI = &load_class('URI', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the routing class and set the routing
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $RTR = &load_class('Router', 'core');
    $RTR->_set_routing();

    // Set any routing overrides that may exist in the main index file
    if (isset($routing)) {
    $RTR->_set_overrides($routing);
    }

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the output class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $OUT = &load_class('Output', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Is there a valid cache file?  If so, we're done...
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
if ($EXT->_call_hook('cache_override') === false) {
    if ($OUT->_display_cache($CFG, $URI) == true) {
        exit;
    }
}

/*
 * -----------------------------------------------------
 * Load the security class for xss and csrf support
 * -----------------------------------------------------
 */
$SEC = &load_class('Security', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the Input class and sanitize globals
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
    $IN = &load_class('Input', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the Language class
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
$LANG = &load_class('Lang', 'core');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Load the app controller and local controller
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *
 */
    // Load the base controller class
    require BASEPATH.'core/Controller.php';

function &get_instance()
{
    return CI_Controller::get_instance();
}

if (file_exists(APPPATH.'core/'.$CFG->config['subclass_prefix'].'Controller.php')) {
    require APPPATH.'core/'.$CFG->config['subclass_prefix'].'Controller.php';
}

// Load the local application controller
// Note: The Router class automatically validates the controller path using the router->_validate_request().
// If this include fails it means that the default controller in the Routes.php file is not resolving to something valid.
if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->fetch_directory().$RTR->fetch_class().'.php')) {
    show_error('Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.');
}

include APPPATH.'controllers/'.$RTR->fetch_directory().$RTR->fetch_class().'.php';

// Set a mark point for benchmarking
$BM->mark('loading_time:_base_classes_end');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Security check
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *
 *  None of the functions in the app controller or the
 *  loader class can be called via the URI, nor can
 *  controller functions that begin with an underscore
 */
$class = $RTR->fetch_class();
$method = $RTR->fetch_method();

if (!class_exists($class)
    or strncmp($method, '_', 1) == 0
    or in_array(strtolower($method), array_map('strtolower', get_class_methods('CI_Controller')))
    ) {
    if (!empty($RTR->routes['404_override'])) {
        $x = explode('/', $RTR->routes['404_override']);
        $class = $x[0];
        $method = (isset($x[1]) ? $x[1] : 'index');
        if (!class_exists($class)) {
            if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class.'.php')) {
                show_404("{$class}/{$method}");
            }

            include_once APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class.'.php';
        }
    } else {
        show_404("{$class}/{$method}");
    }
}

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Is there a "pre_controller" hook?
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
$EXT->_call_hook('pre_controller');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Instantiate the requested controller
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
// Mark a start point so we can benchmark the controller
$BM->mark('controller_execution_time_( '.$class.' / '.$method.' )_start');

$CI = new $class();

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Is there a "post_controller_constructor" hook?
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
$EXT->_call_hook('post_controller_constructor');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Call the requested method
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
// Is there a "remap" function? If so, we call it instead
if (method_exists($CI, '_remap')) {
    $CI->_remap($method, array_slice($URI->rsegments, 2));
} else {
    // is_callable() returns TRUE on some versions of PHP 5 for private and protected
    // methods, so we'll use this workaround for consistent behavior
    if (!in_array(strtolower($method), array_map('strtolower', get_class_methods($CI)))) {
        // Check and see if we are using a 404 override and use it.
        if (!empty($RTR->routes['404_override'])) {
            $x = explode('/', $RTR->routes['404_override']);
            $class = $x[0];
            $method = (isset($x[1]) ? $x[1] : 'index');
            if (!class_exists($class)) {
                if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class.'.php')) {
                    show_404("{$class}/{$method}");
                }

                include_once APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class.'.php';
                unset($CI);
                $CI = new $class();
            }
        } else {
            show_404("{$class}/{$method}");
        }
    }

    // Call the requested method.
    // Any URI segments present (besides the class/function) will be passed to the method for convenience
    call_user_func_array(array(&$CI, $method), array_slice($URI->rsegments, 2));
}

// Mark a benchmark end point
$BM->mark('controller_execution_time_( '.$class.' / '.$method.' )_end');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Is there a "post_controller" hook?
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
$EXT->_call_hook('post_controller');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Send the final rendered output to the browser
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
if ($EXT->_call_hook('display_override') === false) {
    $OUT->_display();
}

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Is there a "post_system" hook?
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
$EXT->_call_hook('post_system');

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 *  Close the DB connection if one exists
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
if (class_exists('CI_DB') and isset($CI->db)) {
    $CI->db->close();
}

/* End of file CodeIgniter.php */
/* Location: ./system/core/CodeIgniter.php */
```

Full Controller.php

```
<?php
 if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
 exit('No direct script access allowed');
 }
 /**
 * CodeIgniter.
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2014, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 *
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * CodeIgniter Application Controller Class.
 *
 * This class object is the super class that every library in
 * CodeIgniter will be assigned to.
 *
 * @category    Libraries
 *
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 *
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html
 */
class CI_Controller
{
private static $instance;

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    self::$instance = &$this;

    // Assign all the class objects that were instantiated by the
    // bootstrap file (CodeIgniter.php) to local class variables
    // so that CI can run as one big super object.
    foreach (is_loaded() as $var => $class) {
        $this->$var = &load_class($class);
    }

    $this->load = &load_class('Loader', 'core');

    $this->load->initialize();

    log_message('debug', 'Controller Class Initialized');
}

public static function &get_instance()
{
    return self::$instance;
}
}
// END Controller class

/* End of file Controller.php */
/* Location: ./system/core/Controller.php */
```

thanks for you time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758681/codeigniter-class-ci-controller-not-found

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207937/codeigniter-command-line-error-php-fatal-error-class-ci-controller-not-foun

Comment: Please confirm this if I am not mistaken: you want us to fix already tested CodeIgniter code without seeing your code itself?

Comment: Make sure have named controller files and classes like http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam the codes that i provided, are what i have on my system but i was seeking to find someone to tell me where is the problem with my code and how to fix it, because i searched and followed many solutions but they didn't work for me.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 i still don't understand what you suggested me to do!

thanks all for your time and helping me with this

Comment: May be download free copy of codeigniter from here https://www.codeigniter.com/download

Answer (score 2):

what will you do?

if just call a controller class. you can write the controller like this.

```
 <?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class YourControllerName extends CI_Controller {

 }
```

Comment: Only the first letter should be upper case http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: still it doesn't function for me

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and the actual cause of this error was my **wrong database configuration settings**. It was a kind of misleading error message.

Fixing my database configuration settings present inside **`application/config`** folder solved the issue for me.

This [article](https://eftakhairul.com/weird-error-fatal-error-class-ci_controller-not-found-in-codeigniter-framework/) was helpful which pointed me to look in the database configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue **'Ci_Controller not found in /Codeigniter.php line 234**
with CI framework 2.2.1 version. 
**1-** I ve downloaded the same project version from github
**2-** I moved all of my controllers,models,views,assets from my origin project to the new downloaded project
Then it's working, unfortunately without knowing the source of the issue.