# Codeigniter 3.0.6 - Sql Server Connection

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, codeigniter-3

I am having problems connecting to sqlserver with Codeigniter

in database.php

```
$db['mssql'] = array(
'dsn'       => '',
'hostname' => 'HostName',
'username' => 'XXXX',
'password' => 'XXXXX',
'database' => 'databaseName',
'dbdriver' => 'sqlsrv',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => false,
'db_debug' => TRUE,
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'autoinit' => TRUE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
```

);

when run in this way

> Class 'CI_Controller' not found in ... in line 366

I get an error.

in ***php.ini***

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
```

extension=php_sqlsrv.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll

Thanks.

Comment: You get his error `Class 'CI_Controller' not found in ... in line 366`? Then why did you write extensions here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter: Class 'CI\_Controller' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6758681/1255289)